# Bash - binary operator expected

Tags: bash

I've got bash script for counting rows in the reports. I have one array where all reports names are stored and in the loop I'm counting rows. However for some files my script receives binary operator expected error. Do anyone have a solution?

```
for i in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
if [ ! -f "$BASE_DIR/$i"* ];
then
        echo "File not generated yet"
else
        ARRAY2=$(wc -l < "$BASE_DIR/$i"*.tab | awk '{print $1-2}')
        echo ${ARRAY2[$i]} $i
fi
```

Comment: You might be aware of the fact that `*` in this context will do globbing

Comment: globbing is used on purpose, cause there is also text before filename and extension

Comment: sjsam thanks for help, there was problem

Answer (score 2):

Use double straight braces instead of ones as follows since you r using extended expressions.

```
if [[ ! -f "$BASE_DIR/$i"* ]];
```

Need to check with array contents. Special characters as ' ' (spaces) in file names must be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

`-f` takes just *one* argument, so the error occurs when the pattern matches more than one file.

It *seems* to work with `[[`, although I can't find any documentation as to *why* it does.

The bigger problem is you can also only use one file with the `<` operator; if the pattern matches multiple files, you'll get an ambiguous redirect error. To fix that, you'll need to use `cat`:

```
cat "$BASE_DIR/$i"*.tab | wc -l
```

However, it's not clear what you are expecting from the output; `ARRAY2` will not actually be an array.

Comment: yeah, as @sjsam has mentioned the problem is with globbing, I have found out that I have some files with .bak in the end